# European consultant: living and working in the USA, employed in Canada

Tags: united-states, taxes, canada, tax-residency

I am from Europe and a consultant employed by a Canadian University, but I live in the USA (I moved to the USA as my husband received a J1 visa). So now I am trying to figure out where to pay taxed? Do I pay taxes to that the USA, or to Canada (in non of these countries I have a social security number). Can anyone give me a advice?
Thank you.

Comment: You probably have to **file** in both countries.  (Maybe also in your home country!)  I'm betting there's a tax treaty so you don't double pay.

Comment: Thank you Chris! I know the regulation in my home country, Sweden, if I live more than six months outside Sweden, then I have to pay taxes in my host country (USA). But what about Canada? Well, I will contact the Us tax agency and ask once again :) Thank you.